# Failed to start Light Display Manager, stuck on black screen

Tags: linux-mint, display, lightdm

I have been using Linux Mint for about a month. Today, I turned on my computer and first I got this error after the Linux Mint logo appeared.

```
UBSAN: array-index-out.of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.50/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.c
index is out of range for type 'SUPGIPCPU [1]'
```

Then, I started my computer in Recovery Mode, as root, and removed virtualbox because I seldom use it. Now, the error doesn't appear any more! However my computer, after the Linux Mint logo appears, is stuck on a black screen. I cannot use it.

Again, I logged in as root in recovery mode and execute this command:

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

and

```
journalctl -xeu lightdm.service
```

I found this error:

> *Failed to start Light Display Manager*

lightdm.service

> *Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes*

GPU-MANAGER service

I reviewed the status of these services and both are inactive. When I activate them nothing happens, the system is still stuck on a black screen.

My OS information is:

- Kernel: 6.5.0-21 generic
- OS: Linux Mint 21.3 (Ubuntu 22.04.1)
- Architecture: x86_64
- Processor: Ryzen 7 5600g

Comment: When you removed VirtualBox, did you also remove `virtualbox-dkms`?

Comment: Also, what happens if you press *Ctrl* + *Alt* + *F2*?

Comment: Hi, guys, thanks a lot for your answers. I can solve the error using Ctrl+Alt+F2, I realized  the problem was NOMACHINE when I uninstalled it the NX server configuration was not deleted, and that was causing problems with starting the Light Display Manager